# XSLT to covert XML file to csv with to total record count added in Trailer

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT and really hoping someone can help me out. I get an XML document from program and I need to be able to convert this to a CSV file with footer record having total number of row in result file. Here is an example of the XML File:
I tried some readily available xslt but I getting error.

```
<Content xmlns="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07">
  <ExportXML>
    <record>
      <field name="Number">12663342</field>
      <field name="FileName">Document.pdf</field>
      <field name="LastModificationDate">2022-07-17 16:31:29</field>
    </record>
    <record>
      <field name="Number">12663324</field>
      <field name="FileName">Rishabh's| Resume.pdf</field>
      <field name="LastModificationDate">2022-07-17 06:38:44</field>
    </record>
  </ExportXML>
</Content>
```

here is the xslt code

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:itk="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07" xmlns:fct="http://www.taleo.com/xsl_functions" xmlns:quer="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/query">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:param name="csvDelimiter">"</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="csvQuoteCharacter">"</xsl:param>
    <!-- ======================================= -->
    <!-- Root template. -->
    <!-- ======================================= -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        
        <!-- Process records. -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//itk:record"/>
        <!-- Build trailer record. -->
        <xsl:text>TRL</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(count(//itk:record), '000000000')"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    
    <!-- ======================================= -->
    <!-- Template matching each record. -->
    <!-- ======================================= -->
    <xsl:template match="itk:record">
        <xsl:for-each select="itk:field">
            <xsl:value-of select="fct:quote(.)"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:value-of select="$csvDelimiter"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:function name="fct:nvl">
        <xsl:param name="value"/>
        <xsl:param name="replace-with"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length($value) &gt; 0">
                <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$replace-with"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:function>
    </xsl:template>
    
        <!-- ======================================= -->
    <!-- Quote a value if it contains the csvDelimiter or the csvQuoteCharacter. -->
    <!-- ======================================= -->
    <xsl:function name="fct:quote">
        <xsl:param name="value"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($value, $csvDelimiter) or contains($value, $csvQuoteCharacter)">
                <xsl:value-of select="$csvQuoteCharacter"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="replace($value, $csvQuoteCharacter, concat($csvQuoteCharacter, $csvQuoteCharacter))"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$csvQuoteCharacter"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:function>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected result should be csv with below format file format

```
12663342|Document.pdf|2022-07-17 16:31:29
12663324|"Rishabh's| Resume.pdf"|2022-07-17 06:38:44
TRL|2
```

I am facing error with above code. your help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks,
Sandeep

Comment: You are getting an error because one of your functions is within a template. Move it to top-level and the error will be gone.

Comment: And if you replace the `csvDelimiter` param with a pipe, and remove the number formatting for the last row, you will get the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't state what error you get, but I assume it's that the `xsl:function` element that declares the `fct:nvl` function is a child of an `xsl:template` element rather than a child of the `xsl:stylesheet` element. Just move the `xsl:function` up a level so that it's a child of the stylesheet.

Comment: You're welcome, @sandeephimgire ! If the answer has fixed your problem, would you please accept it? Thanks!